# Проверка введенного телефона с использованием маски ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть поле ввода телефона. Движек и рядом стоящие сервисы хотят использовать телефоны без +7 или 8

На это поле воода стоит обычная маска ввода.
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
Маска задается

```
$("#telephone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

В итоге мы видим:  (___) __-____

Юзвери часто не замечают в маске +7 и вводят телефоны начиная с 8

Вопрос. Как отследить первый введенный символ и удалить +7 или 8?

```
$('.limitInput').keyup(function(){
var count = $(this).val().length;
alert(count);});
```

не срабатывает, так как alert(count) всегда выдаст 14 символов (маской символы уже заданы).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить "`+7`" в маску, а затем вырезать эти символы на этапе обработки формы (либо на клиенте, либо на сервере). Сам код может выглядеть так:

```
$("#telephone").mask("+7 (999) 999-9999");
$('#submit-btn').click(function() {
    var phone = $('#telephone').val().replace(/^\+7\s/, '');

    // ... А здесь должен быть код, использующий телефон в нужном формате
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p5edtogz/1/

Answer (score 0):

В http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ 
можете создать свою маску. Если хотите что первый символ не был +7 или 8,
то  добавьте в код:

```
$.mask.definitions['~']='[01234569]'; // Первая цифра не может быть 7 или 8.
$("#telephone").mask("(~99) 999-9999");
```